# Iterate over a Tensor flow Placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow

***docArray*** is a placeholder used to build the *tensorflow* graph. The graph is built properly but when the data is fed using feed_dict in session, the variable length do not get adjusted dynamically. Following is the code snippet.

```
lContext = tf.zeros((100,1), dtype=tf.float64)
rContext = tf.zeros((100,1), dtype=tf.float64)
for i in range(1, docArray.shape[1].valu):
    j = docArrayShape - 1 - i
    lContext = tf.concat([lContext,somefun1()], 1)
    rContext = tf.concat([somefun2(), rContext], 1)       
X = tf.concat([lContext, docArray, rContext], axis= 0)
```

When this code is used as forward pass, error comes up when docArray is initialised as
    docArray = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [100, None])

In case i randomly initialise the docArray with random shape, while feeding the realtime docArray data of shape (100 x N), where N is number of words in a document, i get error while training when concatenating, as the lContext and docArray will be in different shape.

The size of sample document is not fixed.

Thanks in advance, for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not mentioned what is the size of the variables during the time of concatenation, it is difficult to estimate where it is going wrong. But in general, for concatenation to take place, the tensors undergoing concatenation should have same `dtype` and same dimensions in all axis except the axis which is undergoing concatenation.

For example,

Not allowed: (different `dtype`)

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (100, None))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, (100, None))
z = tf.concat((x,y), axis = 0)
```

Not allowed: (shape of 100 and 200 mismatch)

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (100, None))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (200, None))
z = tf.concat((x,y), axis = 1)
```

Allowed: (Same `dtype` and axis match)

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (100, 300))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (200, 300))
z = tf.concat((x,y), axis = 0)
```

In above example, if using `None` like other example, it will compile, but during run-time, the `None` has to represent same shape.